# angular 7 unit test throws env.configure is not a function\nat and hangs

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, angular7

I am getting this error:

```
"message": "Uncaught TypeError: env.configure is not a function\nat /Users/darrylwagoner/dev/statellite-web-client/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js:74:7\n\nTypeError: env.configure is not a function\n    at /Users/darrylwagoner/dev/statellite-web-client/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js:74:7\n    at /Users/darrylwagoner/dev/statellite-web-client/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js:78:3",
```

I have no idea where to start looking for the problem.  I checked to make sure the json config files were correct against a new project that worked.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved all the issues by upgrading packages.  I used version Lens extension to find out of date jasmine and karma packages and updated them.

First try worked except I got a

`DEPRECATION: Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated, please use the specFilter option in`configure

warning.  I looked and found another karma-jasmine that was out of date.  Upgraded it and everything runs.

I hope this helps someone.